# Hibernate C3P0 hangs when reaches maxpoolsize even with maxidletime set

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

Not really understanding these setting too well at the moment, wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have the following, which I thought was basically saying

1: Minimum number of pooled connections = 5
2: Maximum number of pooled connections = 10
3: How long an idle connection should stay open, 5 seconds (at which point it's closed and becomes available again.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />   
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />  
    <property name="user" value="root" />   
    <property name="password" value="password" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" /> 
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="5" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
</bean>
```

But in my simple little test app, that runs a simple select where id = 1 on a test table, as soon as I get to my 11th 
'search', it app hangs.

Why am I maxed to just 10 connections, even if I wait well over 5 seconds, why are none of the connections freed up?

--
Snippets of my classes:

```
public Object readObject(SessionFactory sessionFactory, String hql, Map<String,Object> args) {
    session = this.openHibernateSession(sessionFactory);

    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

    Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> it = args.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
        query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object> list = query.list();

    this.closeHibernateSession(sessionFactory); // I don't even know if I should need this!
    if (list!=null && list.size() > 0) {
        return list.get(0);
    } else {
        log4j.warn("readObject: List is NULL.");            
        return null;
    }
}

protected Session openHibernateSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}

protected void closeHibernateSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    Session session;
    try {
        if (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()!=null) {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.close();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        log4j.warn("Failed to close current session, set session to null.", ex);

        session = null;
    } 
}
```

Cheers in advance.

---

Yeah, it's pretty much a mess, so I've stripped it right down and found a couple of examples and started again.

```
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session session;
    private Query query;

    @Override
    public UserDetails getUserDetails(Integer id) {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM UserDetails WHERE id = "+id);

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) query.list().get(0);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

And have made a couple of changes to my application-context.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And it seems to work now as I do not get hangs after 10 connections.

Just wondering do I need to bother with session.close(); or should this now be handled already?

Cheers guys.

Comment: If you're now using Spring's "declarative" transaction-management, commiting/closing the Session is now Spring's responsibility. Glad you got it working. (And perhaps an upvote for my/ Nizet's answer, or both -- he's a good guy & his answer is correct too.)

Comment: Still not sure if this is the 'correct' way of doing this, as it seems every Dao is going to need to be @Transactional else the currentSession() is NULL. It's hard to find a clear answer because it seems like each example I find, people do things in a slightly different way. So I don't know which is the best way in regards to best practices, performance, overheads etc etc etc. But this works, so it's an improvement on before! (updated and accepted) :-)

Comment: You can mark `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` (which helps readability, but is mostly just a hint to the underlying transaction system), or you can use the `OpenSessionInView` pattern as I mentioned. Normally Views should be able to load data during rendering.. and would appear to otherwise be outside transactional scope :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're presumably not closing the Connections, to return them to the pool.

`maxPoolSize` is a limiting factor;  if your code hogs the Connections & doesn't `close()` them, C3PO doesn't know they're available for that 11th search.

Idle Time has nothing to do with it. C3PO can't very well close/recycle the connection while you appear to still have it in use, can it? The purpose of Idle Time is to kill off connections that have been idle so long, the DB might have closed them from it's end.

---

The specific issue which prevents your code from closing the Session, is the reliance on  `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. You haven't registered the current Session there, so it doesn't work.

Better to just close the Session directly.

In webapps, I use the Spring OpenSessionInView pattern & some variants (Long Session).

I recommend using/ making some well-defined infrastructure to get the SessionFactory, get Sessions (perhaps bound to the current thread), and bind/unbind Sessions from the current thread.

Putting all this stuff in a well-defined place will help, as your app grows bigger.

Comment: I ran into the same issue (with JPA using Hibernate) and suspect that one long living EntityManager instance is keeping its connection instead of returning it the connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got this code from, but it's wrong. My guess is that `openHibernateSession()` always goes to the catch block, and thus opens a session, because there is no current session.

And then `closeHibernateSession()`, which is not even called in a finally block, tries to get the current session again, still doesn't find any, and thus doesn't do anything. An in particular, it doesn't close the session that has been opened by `openHibernateSession()`.

As a result, as soon as you execute this code 10 times, you still have 10 sessions open, and thus 10 connections that haven't been closed and given back to the connection pool.

Re-read the documentation on Spring and Hibernate integration. You should not open sessions by yourself. Only use `getCurrentSession()`, and let Spring handle them.